# Show that $A$ is $\mu^*-measurable$ iff for every $E\subset X$ such that $\mu^*(E)<\infty$ we have $\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)\leq \mu^*(E)$.

Tags: measure-theory

Show that $A$ is $\mu^*-measurable$ iff for every $E\subset X$ such that $\mu^*(E)<\infty$ we have $\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)\leq \mu^*(E)$.

I know that $\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E \cap A) + \mu^*(E \setminus A)$.

Is it correct that $E\setminus A = E \cap A^c$? I think it does.

Hence I get $\mu^*(E\cap A)+\mu^*(E\cap A^c)= \mu^*(E)$.

I don't get why is there an inequation ? any help how to approach this problem is welcome.

Comment: Because the other direction is always true. Namely as $E=(E\cap A)\cup (E\cap A^{c})$ hence $\mu(E)\leq \mu(E\cap A)+\mu(E\cap A^{c})$ by definition (monotonicity) of outer measure. So one need only show the inequality in the direction given to conclude equality.